# TCPIP Remoting Server side crash on windows 10

Tags: c#, remoting, tcp

I am running my TCPIP remoting server application (.net version 4.5.1, VS 2013) in windows 10 but I got one server side crash given below, infact it’s perfectly working in windows 7
We have  checked port details by "netstat" command and found that the  server side port(9092 is my server port) is in listening state, even though we got following error

**Error : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9092**

I hope the issue will come when the client try to register on the server listening port. 
Is there any change in TCPIP connection/security  settings in Windows 10 ?